# A cada N repetições exibir X no PHP

Tags: php

Estou exercitando os conhecimentos no PHP e me surgiu uma dúvida. Como faço para exibir um texto após N repetições do laço DO?

```
    <?php do { ?>
    <div class="fotos">
    <h1><?php echo $titulo_da_foto; ?></h1>
    <img src="upload/<?php echo $arquivo; ?>" />
    </div>
    <?php } while ($rsVarejo > 0); ?>
```

Neste caso, gostaria de ocultar o background da class fotos na 4ª repetição, alguma sugestão?

Comment: Você quer que a cada 4 fotos oculte e volte a mostrar nas 3 seguintes, e oculte de novo, ou oculte permanentemente da quarta em diante? Seria bom você por um exemplo da saída desejada na pergunta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você poderia fazer isto:

```php
<?php
$counter = 0;
do { 
  $counter++;
  if ($counter == 4){ 
    ?>
      <div class="fotos ocultar">
    <?php 
  }
  else {
    ?>
      <div class="fotos">
    <?php
       }
    ?>
  <h1><?php echo $titulo_da_foto; ?></h1>
  <img src="upload/<?php echo $arquivo; ?>" />
  </div>
<?php
   } while ($rsVarejo > 0); ?>
```

E adicionar uma classe CSS `"ocultar"`:

```css
.ocultar {
  background: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução possível, seria em jquery:

```
 $( ".classdesejada:nth-child(4)" ).css("background", "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)" );
```

Answer (score 1):

Acho que isso resolve seu problema:

```
<?php 
    $aux = 0;
    do { 
          $aux++;
          if($aux >= 4){
              $nomeDaClasse = 'classe';
              $aux = 0;
          }
?>
          <div class="<?php echo $nomeDaClasse;?>">
             <h1><?php echo $titulo_da_foto; ?></h1>
             <img src="upload/<?php echo $arquivo; ?>" />
          </div>
<?php 
       } while ($rsVarejo > 0);
?>
```

Answer (score -5):

```
<?php    
    $fim = 100;
    $incremento = 1;
    $diferente = 4;
    $contador=0;
    do {  
        $contador = $contador + $incremento;
        $resto = contador % diferente;
        ?><div class="<?php
        if ( $resto != 0 ) {
        echo $id_do_estilo_css_normal;
       } else {
       echo $id_do_estilo_css_diferente;
     }
     ?>">Conteudo do elemento, tag, etiqueta
    </div>
    } while ( $contador < $fim); 
?>
```

Recomendações:
O estilo de codificação original desta postagem deve ser repensada. 
Nele há mistura de camadas conceituais. Não se utiliza esse estilo de concepção de projeto por diversas razões. Estude e utilize o modelo Model, View, Controller entre outros modelos para atualizar seu aprendizado.

A todos desejo MUITA boa sorte nos estudos e obrigado por lerem este texto.

Comment: `$resto = $contador % $n_interacoes;`